# Error in MyActivity.java file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to Android development and I have searched for this question but i couldn't get correct answer.
After installing and creating the basic activity project in the Android Studio, It continuously gives me @override class error in `MyActivity.java`. I think something was missed during installation.
Kindly give me the suggestions or tips to correct this error.

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Try clean & build project by choosing build -> clean & build project in Android Studio